# Why is it wrong to use "(removed)" meme?

Tags: support, chat

Recently, I was banned from Chat (it is now in read-only for me). Reason: I was using *(removed)* text.

Well, what's wrong with it? I don't think it's offensive or something bad.

I was just using it as meme. And, there's nothing new here. Such system message based memes are in existence since 90s. So, I don't think it's wrong. If admins have problem with it, the better way is to modify the system message to distinguish it from user text (like highlight *(removed)* in a fancy way).

Comment: Doing it once is a nod to a meme. [Doing it 10 times](http://chat.stackexchange.com/search?user=8479&q=removed) is simply annoying people (and it doesn't actually matter wether it's "(removed)" or something else). You've been [asked before by a moderator to stop doing it](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/198?m=20250150#20250150) and you decided to ignore that hint, and thus you got a stronger message this time. You'll be able to chat again in 10 hours without any grudges held, but please stop getting on people's nerves.

Comment: @balpha Oh, I thought he was participating in the humor to make others fool. `(removed)` ~> `Knock that off` From other's perspective, it looks like he removed my message and then replied.

Comment: Actually, it appeared to me that *you* removed your own message, and then @Keen replied to you, giving you a warning to "knock it off" and to stop posting messages and removing them. This is my interpretation of both times you were asked to stop. Is your meme wrong? I don't know, but I've been online since the 90s and have never heard of the "removed" meme -- this is purely anecdotal, of course. It strikes me as an incredibly silly use of chat, but if this is the impression you want to impart, well I suppose it's your prerogative.

Comment: @Slytherincess What you understood should also do. My meme worked. As for meme, I said "system message based meme"..

Comment: Regardless of the name of your meme, if you meant appearing to be socially awkward and without understanding of the dynamics of chat, then, yes, your meme worked.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here are three reasons why it's was inappropriate to keep posting it:

- **It's not funny when you do it repeatedly.**

  You posted "(removed)" [at least ten times](http://chat.stackexchange.com/search?user=8479&q=removed). Maybe it was funny the first or second time, but not the tenth. It was just noise for everybody to scroll past. Did you expect a better response on subsequent postings?
- **It could be seen as deception.**

  You have a history of posting annoying or offensive messages in chat. They get flagged and removed, so it's not implausible that these are genuinely deleted messages.

  Unless you look carefully, it's not obvious that it's just a regular message. It's easy to assume that you've posted something offensive again. Can you see why people could find that deceptive?
- **You were asked to stop by a moderator.**

  Keen asked you <s>on at least twice ([1](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/198?m=20250150#20250150), [2](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/198?m=20352037#20352037))</s> to stop posting it. [*Amended:* per comments, the second “ask” was explaining the chat ban.] Didn't that give you a hint that the joke was lost on everybody else?

  (I'm afraid I don't buy the idea that you thought they were “in on the joke”, so to speak. This isn't the first time you've been posting annoying messages in chat, and ignored multiple requests to desist. Why are you unable to respond to a reasonable request?)

A more general comment:

> If admins have problem with it, the better way is to modify the system message to distinguish it from user text (like highlight *(removed)* in a fancy way).

The better way is to behave like an adult. Don't try to trick people with an unfunny joke, and listen when you're asked to stop. If you can't behave properly, then the problem isn't with the site's design or policies, it's with you.

---

**Footnote on design:**

For whatever it's worth, there are already different styles. Actually removed messages have a grey tint, while messages with the text "(removed) are shown in white. It's subtle, but it's there:

[image]

But that's easy to miss if you're just skimming chat, and it's not an excuse.

Comment: On mobile site, *(removed)* isn't grey tinted..

Comment: The second warning you linked came after the ban. So, it can't be assumed warning.

Comment: The second 'ask' there is me explaining why they're suspended from chat.

Comment: @SS Duly noted and amended. I thought you were only banned in the last hour or so.

Comment: @Keen You could have said `Stop using (removed)`..

Comment: @SS Keen could have said a lot of things but kept it succinct. As a direct reply to one of your `(removed)`, it should have been obvious.

Comment: @Pureferret Unfortunately, it wasn't obvious. I thought he participated in the humor.

Comment: @ss this is why I said it *should* have been obvious. I don't see how what keen said could have been any differently.